# Finding new memory address? C++

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

(I tested the address because I was getting errors and I found out the address changed before it was deleted, by the time the delete is called the `titlePTR` has already changed its address and it is giving me an error saying "`BLOCK TYPE IS VALID`" I heard this is when you try to delete a pointer that wasn't made by new (So that made me think about the address)

Btw I know I don't have to make a dynamic array but I am reading a book and it is saying to practice saving memory for times where your program doesn't need to run the code. I posted on a few other places and people always nag about "Don't use new blah blah blah"

Here is what is says when it trys to delete `titlePTR` or `bodyPTR`:
http://postimg.org/image/gt0f8kufn/

```
if (test == "MapleStory")
{
    wchar_t *titlePTR = new wchar_t[30]; <-- Example Address: 051
    cout << titlePTR;
    wchar_t *bodyPTR = new wchar_t[20];
    titlePTR = L"MapleStory";
    bodyPTR = L"Launching MapleStory...";
    MessageBox(NULL, bodyPTR, titlePTR, MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    ShellExecute(NULL, L"open", L"GameLauncher.exe", NULL, L"C:\\Nexon\\MapleStory", 1);
    cout << endl << titlePTR; <-- Example Address: 0601 
    delete[] titlePTR;
    delete[] bodyPTR;
}
```

Comment: you're changing your pointer during assignment `titlePTR = L"MapleStory";`, consider using strcpy (or wchar analogs) here

Comment: `"...but I am reading a book and it is saying to practice saving memory for times where your program doesn't need to run the code."` the book title is "stoned C++ programming"?

Comment: `Btw I know I don't have to make a dynamic array` Well, `std::vector<wchar_t>`  this creates a dynamic array, without all the issues.  Even with that, `std::basic_string<wchar_t>` does an even better job.  All of these constructs do not require pointer or manual memory management.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I would say `std::wstring` is more suitable here (OK, I wrote comment before seeing your edit). `vector` isn't equivalent to dynamic array, it has its own issues. `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` is closer, but I still miss standard dynamic array counterpart to `std::array`.

Comment: `people always nag about "Don't use new blah blah blah"`  It is more than "nag".  If for some reason, those API functions you're calling throw an exception (an OS exception, but still an exception), you have no chance of getting to the lines that call `delete[]`.  In other words, you have a memory leak.

Comment: @doc dynamic array usually means `std::vector`.  However for the purposes of the OP, you are right that `std::wstring` would be the best container to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
wchar_t *titlePTR = new wchar_t[30];   // (1)
titlePTR = L"MapleStory";              // (2)
delete[] titlePTR;                     // (3)
```

This allocates memory and stores the address of the memory in the variable (1). Then you overwrite it with a new address (2). And then you delete the new address (3), instead of the allocated memory. 
So your problem is that the assignment in step (2) doesn't use the buffer you prepared but creates a new buffer.

To fix, just do:

```
const wchar_t *titlePTR = L"MapleStory";
```

And don't delete of course, since you didn't allocate any memory using `new`.

Comment: Thanks man! I knew it was that line but I just didn't know if there was a way I could simply write the it inside of the allocated address. I guess char/wchar_t[] doesn't work like int's. (Because array's of char/wchar_t already use pointers/address's internally. 

But thank you again, people always just said I was wrong without fully telling me why and how it was.

Comment: No problem. You can mark this answer as the answer that helped you in order to close this question.